# Sending an Email with Godaddy contact form using gmail

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to send a email using the contact form. I am using godaddy as my hosting provider.

The following error will come

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I am using asp.net with c# and I am writing the code in same file which is contact.aspx.cs
Format of contact form:

My markup:

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="3" class="style32">
                <span style="color: #009966; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 16pt;">
                <strong></strong></span>
                <span style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 16px;" class="requiredText">
                <strong class="style25">Enter Your Details</strong></span><br />

            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td align="right" class="style14">
                <span style="font-family: Verdana" class="style23">
                Name</span>
                <span style="color: #ff0033"> *</span>
                </td>

            <td class="style31">:
            </td>

            <td class="style33">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9.6pt"
                    Width="232px" BorderColor="GrayText" BorderStyle="Solid"  Height="32px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
        </tr>

         <tr>
            <td align="right" class="style24">
                Mobile No</span>
                <span style="color: #ff0033"> *</span>
               </td>
            <td class="style13">:
            </td>
            <td class="style34">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMobileNo" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9.6pt"
                    Width="232px" BorderColor="GrayText" BorderStyle="Solid" Height="32px"></asp:TextBox><span style="color: #ff0033"> </span>
                </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="font-size: 12pt">
            <td class="style11" align="right">
                <span style="font-family: Verdana"><span class="style23">
                E-mail </span></span>
                <span style="font-family: Verdana"><span style="font-size: 0.8em">
                <span style="color: #ff0033" class="style23">*</span></span></span></td>
            <td class="style13">:
            </td>
            <td class="style34">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9.6pt"
                    Width="232px" BorderColor="GrayText" BorderStyle="Solid" Height="32px"></asp:TextBox>

            </td>
        </tr>

         <tr style="font-size: 12pt">
             <td class="style11" align="right">
                <span style="font-family: Verdana"><span class="style23">
                Message</span></span>
                <span style="font-family: Verdana"><span style="font-size: 0.8em">
                <span style="color: #ff0033" class="style23">*</span></span></span></td>
            <td class="style13">:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9.6pt"
                    TextMode="MultiLine" Width="232px" BorderColor="GrayText" 
                    BorderStyle="Solid" Height="62px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="font-size: 12pt">
        <td class="style14"></td>
        <td class="style31"></td>
            <td class="style28">
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="11pt" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"
                    Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="first" BorderColor="GrayText" 
                    BorderStyle="Solid" BackColor="Red" ForeColor="White" />

            </td>
        </tr>

    <tr>
    <td class="style14">
        &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My Contact.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class Contact : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //string strCS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ToString();
    string Adsfile, strBodymessage;
    string strMobileNo;

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string strLandline = txtLandCountryCode.Text + "-" + 
        txtLandCityCode.Text +          "-" + txtLandlineNo.Text;
        strMobileNo = txtMobileNo.Text;

        Sendmail(txtEmail.Text);
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ele", " 
         <script> alert('example.com<br>
   Information Successfully Send to Your SMS/Email !.');</script>");

        ResetAll();
    }

    public void Sendmail(string ToID)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient c = new SmtpClient();
        msg.From = new MailAddress("xxxx@gmail.com", "example.com");
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(ToID));

        msg.Subject = "Response to Your Message.<br> www.example.com";

        strBodymessage = "Dear <b>" + txtName.Text + "</b>,<br>";
        strBodymessage += " Mobile no : <b>" + strMobileNo + "</b>,<br>";
        strBodymessage += "<br>   <b> Conformation Mail</b>:<br><br> Message<br>";
        strBodymessage += "<br>  We hope the Above Information is Useful for You<br>  <br>";
        strBodymessage += "<b>    Thankyou for Contacting us!</b><br>
        Help Line No:   xxxxxxx<br>";
        msg.Body = strBodymessage;

        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        c.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        c.EnableSsl = true;
        c.Port = 587;
        c.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        c.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxx@gmail.com", "pwd");
        c.Send(msg);
    }

    public void ResetAll()
    {
        txtName.Text = "";
        txtMobileNo.Text = "";
        txtEmail.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Name :     textbox,

Telephone: Textbox,

Email: textbox(Visitor Email Id)

Message: Visitor message

Submit button

When user enter the details and submits the page, I should receive the email (yyyy@example.com)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest turning off CustomErrors first, so you can see the exception it throws.

Anyway, simple code like

Markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="Message" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"  />
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="SendEmail_Click" />
```

Code:

```
protected void SendEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress(Email.Text);

message.To.Add(new MailAddress("YourEmailAddress"));

message.Subject = "New message from Web";
message.Body = Message.Text;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(message);

}
```

Should work, of course, supposing your SMTP is configured in the Web.config file.

Comment: Sir can you give me the brief explanation, using my codes u can edit the error place and give me sir

Comment: I do not see any issue just when looking at the code, so I do not think there is an issue. Turn off customErrors for exception the SmtpClient probably throws. Or use try catch in there. And turn off your UseDefaultCredentials, as you are not using default, which could be the issue as unauthorized.